# Has anybody got "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" when using Java-Prolog Connector

Tags: java, prolog

I wonder if anyone has used Java-Prolog Connector (https://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/connector/start) and met "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" before.

My code is like

```
PrologProcess process = Connector.newPrologProcess();
while(condition) {
    process.restart();
    PrologSession session = process.getSession();
    session.queryOnce(assertz(...));
    String query = ...;
    Map<String, Object> query_result = session.queryOnce(query);
    session.dispose();
}
```

So what I'm basically trying to do is to iteratively build sessions and get query results while condition holds. However, it does not always work, and it seems that if there are too many iterations I may get "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" and fail to obtain sessions. Has anybody used the same tool and met the same issue? Thanks!

Below is the detailed exception message:

```
org.cs3.prolog.connector.process.PrologProcessException: Failed to obtain session
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.AbstractPrologProcess.getSession(AbstractPrologProcess.java:371)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.AbstractPrologProcess.getSession(AbstractPrologProcess.java:346)
    at com.example.demo.Search.is_done(Search.java:5363)
    at com.example.demo.Search.main(Search.java:1156)
Caused by: org.cs3.prolog.connector.process.PrologProcessException: java.io.IOException: EndOfStream read while waiting for OK
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.lifecycle.AbstractState.error(AbstractState.java:117)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.lifecycle.LifeCycle$3.run(LifeCycle.java:226)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.lifecycle.LifeCycle$DispatcherThread.run(LifeCycle.java:59)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: EndOfStream read while waiting for OK
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.readUntil(SocketClient.java:185)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.readUntil(SocketClient.java:142)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.reset(SocketClient.java:105)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.<init>(SocketClient.java:60)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketPrologProcess.getSession_impl(SocketPrologProcess.java:163)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.AbstractPrologProcess.getSession_internal(AbstractPrologProcess.java:379)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.AbstractPrologProcess.getSession(AbstractPrologProcess.java:369)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.AbstractPrologProcess.getSession(AbstractPrologProcess.java:346)
    at com.example.demo.Search.is_done(Search.java:5363)
    at com.example.demo.Search.main(Search.java:1156)

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.InputStreamProxy.read(InputStreamProxy.java:79)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.readUntil(SocketClient.java:174)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.readUntil(SocketClient.java:142)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.reset(SocketClient.java:105)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.<init>(SocketClient.java:60)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketClient.<init>(SocketClient.java:53)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketServerStartAndStopStrategy.getSocketClient(SocketServerStartAndStopStrategy.java:355)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketServerStartAndStopStrategy.stopSocketServer(SocketServerStartAndStopStrategy.java:335)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketServerStartAndStopStrategy.stopServer(SocketServerStartAndStopStrategy.java:326)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.AbstractPrologProcess$MyLifeCycle.stopServer(AbstractPrologProcess.java:234)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.lifecycle.ErrorState$1.run(ErrorState.java:48)
    at org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.lifecycle.LifeCycle$DispatcherThread.run(LifeCycle.java:59)
```

Comment: Seems the Prolog server cuts the connection before sending "OK". Is there a log file of the server side?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but sry I'm very new to swipl-win, could you please tell me where I can find the log file?

Comment: I really don't know. I have noticed that you seem to be using old code from 2015 because the exception message show in your output has changed on June 9, 2015. Maybe updating to a later version of the Java library might help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue remains even with the newest version of the Java library. As @David Tonhofer suggests, the issue seems to be due to something wrong with the socket connection. While I still find no way to completely solve this problem, I here put forward a somehow naive and direct solution in case someone may meet the same problem.

Below is the sample code:

```
{
    ...
    PrologProcess process = Connector.newPrologProcess();
    while(condition) {
        myFunction(process,...);
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM swipl-win.exe /F");
    ...
}

private static int myFunction(PrologProcess process) {    
    try {
        process.restart();
        PrologSession session = process.getSession();
        try {
            session.queryOnce(assertz(...));
            String query = ...;
            Map<String, Object> query_result = session.queryOnce(query);
            session.dispose();
            ...
        }
        catch(Exception) {
            ...
        }
    }
    try {
        process = Connector.newPrologProcess();
        return myFunction(process);
    }
}
```

So the idea is to use recursion to create a new Prolog process whenever a "fail to obtain sessions" exception occurs, and at the end of the program use "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM swipl-win.exe /F");" to kill all swipl-win.exe that are created during the process and may remain there because of the exception.